# Shared instance issue in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a shared instance but it says that not allowed!

please see the image below and give me the advice

[image]

Comment: make `sharedInstance` static

Comment: You should access as `ModelManager.sharedInstance`, but before that as others have suggested, you need to declare it as `static let sharedInstance`

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`static let sharedInstance = ModelManager()`
and then declare your initializer as `private`

```
private init() {
    database = FMDatabase(init: SomeObject)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```
class SomeSingleton {
    internal static let sharedInstance = SomeSingleton()

    // Your singleton properties
    var name = "" 

    private init() { }
}
```

**Then you can access it like:**

```
SomeSingleton.sharedInstance.name = "John"

let currentName = SomeSingleton.sharedInstance.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to access instance properties on class or static functions. A workaround would be to make the sharedInstance property a static property.

```
static let sharedInstance = ModelManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Method to return shared instance

```
class var sharedInstance :YourClass {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = YourClass()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }
```

Accessing shared instance:

```
let sharedInstance = YourClass.sharedInstance()
```

[Check this link for more Singleton pattern in Swift](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

**Singleton instance:** Use struct with computed property of a classs instead

```
class MyClass :NSObject{
    class var sharedInstance : MyClass {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = MyClass()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
    // do other stuff here
    func getCustomerLists()-> Any{
        //  return
    }
}
```

Accessing:

```
 MyClass.sharedInstance. getCustomerLists()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code formate bellow :-

```
class var sharedInstance: YourClass {
       struct Static {
           static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
           static var instance: YourClass? = nil
       }
       dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        Static.instance = YourClass()
       }
       return Static.instance!
}
```